# Forward someone to someone?

Tags: grammar, verbs

The contest is: I have emailed a colleague (A) for some information about a project. Since he left the company he provided me the email address of the new colleague (B) I have to email. When I email to B may I say, "I was forwarder to you by A" or "A forwarded to you"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is:

> "I was referred to you by A"

You can forward an email, not a person. You were *referred* to B by A.

Also, I don't think this meets the technical definition of a "forwarded" email. Usually, when you "forward", it means that you're passing along an email that you received. If you compose the email and send it to another person (as A did), you're simply sending the email, not forwarding it, per my understanding of how the verb "forward" is used in modern parlance.

Comment: It'd help your proscription to note that dictionaries note that "forward" usually pertains to things, not people. Here's the OED: "a. To send forward, send to an ulterior destination (a thing, **rarely a person**). In commercial language often loosely, to dispatch, send by some regular mode of conveyance."

Comment: I'm not sure what the protocol is here - that would be a great add to my answer, but it seems like I'd be taking credit for your work. Maybe edit my answer?